# Teams Messaging Extension auth URL never gets traffic

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm implementing a Teams Messaging Extension and following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication?view=msteams-client-js-latest) to add authentication. I'm able to send the `auth` response with the `openUrl` action to Teams and that part seems to work, but when I click on the `Sign in` button in Teams I immediately get an error message in the modal: `Something went wrong, please try again` and I don't see any traffic reaching the sign-in endpoint.

I made sure the correct domain is in the `validDomains` list and that the sign-in URL is accessible from the public internet.

This is essentially what I'm returning when authentication is required:

```
      {
        composeExtension: {
          type: 'auth',
          suggestedActions: {
            actions: [
              {
                type: 'openUrl',
                value: 'https://foo.ngrok.io/signin',
                title: 'Please authenticate',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      }
```

and I double-checked the `validDomains` list in the manifest.

Is there something else that has to be done after editing the `validDomains`? Am I missing another requirement?

Comment: You could try this sample code for [Authentication in Teams Message extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config)

Comment: Is it true that the bot registration has to be in Azure for this to work? That might be my problem.

Comment: Microsoft Teams behaves slightly differently than other channels when it comes to authentication. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample on how to add authentication to your teams bot and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#register-your-web-service-with-the-bot-framework for the registration